# My Google Maps Script v3

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, google-maps

[My Google Maps Script v2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83723/my-google-maps-script-v2/83736#83736)

---

I re-factored my code to be more OO.

Does it have any more room for improvement (naming, readability, oop, etc.)?

I'm importing `Gmap.js` in the head tags and the `main.js` just before the closing body tag of the HTML document.

**Gmap.js**

```
'use strict';

function Gmap(element, options) {
    if (!(typeof window.google === 'object' && typeof window.google.maps === 'object')) {
        throw Error('The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 library is required.');
    }

    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options), //TODO: make private
    this.currentLocation = options.center,
    this.markers = []; //TODO: make private
}

Gmap.prototype = {
    addMarker: function (location, animateDrop, bounceOnClick) {
        animateDrop = (typeof animateDrop === 'undefined') ? true : animateDrop;
        bounceOnClick = (typeof bounceOnClick === 'undefined') ? true : bounceOnClick;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.googleMap,
            position: location
        });

        if (animateDrop) {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        }

        if (bounceOnClick) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                    marker.setAnimation(null);
                } else {
                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                }
            });
        }

        this.markers.push(marker);
    },

    deleteAllMarkers: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
            this.markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    },

    getCenter: function () {
        return this.googleMap.getCenter();
    },

    setCenter: function (latLng) {
        this.googleMap.setCenter(latLng);
    },

    fitBounds: function (latLngBounds) {
        this.googleMap.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
    },

    triggerEvent: function (event) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.googleMap, event);
    }
}

Gmap.geocode = function (geocodeRequest, callback) {
    var googleGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    googleGeocoder.geocode(geocodeRequest, function (results, status) {
        callback(results, status);
    });
};

Gmap.geocodeStatus = {
    OK: google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK,
    ZERO_RESULTS: google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS,
    OVER_QUERY_LIMIT: google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT,
    REQUEST_DENIED: google.maps.GeocoderStatus.REQUEST_DENIED,
    UNKNOWN_ERROR: google.maps.GeocoderStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR
};
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

(function (window, document, Gmap) {
    var MAP_CANVAS_ID = 'map-canvas',
        ADDRESS_INPUT_ID = 'address-input',
        SEARCH_BUTTON_ID = 'search-button';

    var gMap,
        mapCanvas = document.getElementById(MAP_CANVAS_ID),
        addressInput = document.getElementById(ADDRESS_INPUT_ID);

    if (!mapCanvas.hasAttribute('data-default-address')) {
        throw new Error('The default address attribute must be present and not empty.');
    }

    if (!mapCanvas.getAttribute('data-default-address').trim()) {
        throw new Error('The default address attribute must not be empty.');
    }

    Gmap.geocode({ 'address': mapCanvas.getAttribute('data-default-address') }, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== Gmap.geocodeStatus.OK) {
            if (status === Gmap.geocodeStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                throw new Error('The address could not be located.');
            }

            throw new Error('Geocode was unsuccessful: ' + status);
        }

        gMap = new Gmap(mapCanvas, {
            // required
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            zoom: 10,
            // disable direct GUI interaction
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });

        addressInput.value = results[0].formatted_address;

        gMap.addMarker(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // center map responsively
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        var center = gMap.getCenter();

        gMap.triggerEvent('resize');
        gMap.setCenter(center);
    });

    addressInput.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            addressInput.blur();

            processAddressInput();
        }
    };

    document.getElementById(SEARCH_BUTTON_ID).onclick = function () {
        processAddressInput();
    };

    function processAddressInput() {
        Gmap.geocode({ 'address': addressInput.value }, function (results, status) {
            if (status !== Gmap.geocodeStatus.OK) {
                if (status === Gmap.geocodeStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    return;
                }

                throw new Error('Geocode was unsuccessful: ' + status);
            }

            if (results[0].geometry.location.equals(gMap.currentLocation)) {
                addressInput.value = results[0].formatted_address;

                return;
            }

            gMap.deleteAllMarkers();

            gMap.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            gMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            gMap.addMarker(results[0].geometry.location);

            gMap.currentLocation = results[0].geometry.location;

            addressInput.value = results[0].formatted_address;
        });
    }
}(window, document, Gmap));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick thoughts:

1. `Gmap` constructor: I'd prefer semicolons instead of commas when you're setting properties on `this`.
2. `addMarker`: I think moving `animateDrop` & `bounceOnClick` into an `options` object would be good, especially if you ever add additional options. In ES6, the syntax makes this all the more apparent:

   ```
   function addMarker(location, {animateDrop = true, bounceOnClick = true} = {}) { ... }
   ```
3. `typeof animateDrop === 'undefined'` is fine, but you can also use `animateDrop === undefined` as there's no risk that `animateDrop` isn't declared.
4. `deleteMarkers`: Cache the length:

   ```
   for (var i=0, l=this.markers.length; i<l; i++) { ... }
   ```
5. Consider using promises for `geocode`.
6. If you're just aliasing all the status constants, why not this:

   ```
   Gmap.geocodeStatus = google.maps.GeocoderStatus;
   ```
7. `'address'` as an object key doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: Can you elaborate point 5? Promises?

Comment: Although the callback pattern works, it's easy to get into callback hell where callbacks are nested within callbacks, etc.

Promises alleviate this by allowing you to write `geocode({address:...}).then(function(results){}).catch(function(err){});` Come ES7, this becomes even nicer with the `await` keyword: `let result = await geocode({address:....});`. 

Granted; you're not in danger of callback hell yet, but thought I would bring it up, especially with the future direction of ES.